# SSMS 2012 / 2014 / 2016 Object Explorer hangs when Expanding Databases list on a server with many DBs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, ssms

When accessing SQL Server with SSMS versions (2012/2014 and 2016), opening the databases list from the object explorer is really slow.
If I try it using SSMS 2008 R2 on the same instance the result is => instant display.

Note : The account is sysadmin, all databases have autoclose disabled, and I am not connecting to a remote server. It's on my local machine!

I noticed that there is a small difference comparing the queries generated from SSMS 2008 and 2012/2014/2016 when opening the databases list.

All of them are using **has_dbaccess** function, except SSMS 2008.

For instance:

```
SELECT
dtb.name AS [Name],
dtb.database_id AS [ID],
CAST(has_dbaccess(dtb.name) AS bit) AS [IsAccessible]
FROM
master.sys.databases AS dtb
ORDER BY
[Name] ASC
```

There is a huge performance difference if I remove the function.
I guess they should add a condition in the begging of the query where in case it's a sysadmin account, just don't check permissions in every single database.
Does it make any sense?

Comment: Well, it is ambiguous, "all databases are not configured with autoclose" means to me that they aren't *all* set to auto-close, but *some* might be, so I can understand why RLF suggested it...

Comment: Have you tried this
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/768124/ssms-2012-object-explorer-hangs-when-expanding-databases-node-on-a-server-with-many-dbs

Comment: Hi @jesijesi. Yes, I've tried this one as well, even saying the problem is related when connecting to remove servers. Thanks!
I really believe the problem is related to that function has_dbaccess. Because when I remove it (it doesn't exist on SSMS 2008) it runs instantaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is finally fixed in the new SSMS 17.9.

You can get it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing from Windows Authentication to SQL Server authentication, as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19841746/3420102). (I realize not everyone can do that.)

The problem is still there in SSMS 18.9 and SQL Server 2019.

The has_dbaccess function definitely seems to be the problem.